# What is -%> in ruby on rails? How is that different from %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The form_for shortcut in TextMate puts in the following:

```
<% form_for @model do |f| -%>

<% end -%>
```

What does the minus sign do here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The minus sign is for removing blank line inside the rendered code.

```
<% form_for @model do |f| -%>

<% end -%>
```

Anyway from Rails 3 the minus is useless, because it automatically removes the blank lines.

Comment: In fact, there's no output at all for ERB snippets ending with `-%>`.